# subprocess.CalledProcessError and ssh connection drops when an ssh command to a Cisco router produces large output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, cisco

I am having some issue with my code.  It works fine when output is small but when output is big it breaks.

Here is my code:

```
def listDevices(username, pass, regex):
    command = "list-dev " + regex
    deviceArray = []
    connectString = "plink -ssh -l " + username + " -pw " + pass + " -P " + SshPort + " " + Server + " \"" + command + "\""
    rawList = subprocess.check_output(connectString, shell=True)
          for line in rawList.split("\r\n"):
              if "" is not line:
                  deviceArray.append(line)
          print deviceArray
          return deviceArray

Server = 10.10.10.1
SshPort = 22 
username = "test"
pass - "password"  
regex = "rt*mdr*"    

mdrList = listDevices(username, pass, regex)
print mdrList
```

This works fine when data is small but fails when the data is big.

Here is the error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'plink -ssh -l test -pw password -P 4000 10.10.10.1 "list-dev *"' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Edit:

I replaced plink and wrote paramiko but still not getting all data.  here is code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,username=username, password=password, port = 9000)
list =["list-devices rt*"]
command = '\n'.join(list)
print command
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
print stdout.read()
```

It gives me below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xx/Scripts/Test2.py", line 31, in <module>
    stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\paramiko\client.py", line 404, in exec_command
    chan.exec_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\paramiko\channel.py", line 60, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python27\paramiko\channel.py", line 229, in exec_command
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "C:\Python27\paramiko\channel.py", line 1086, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
```

Comment: Can you use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to simplify this a bit? You shouldn't need to write to a temp file.

Comment: @Wyatt, This is exactly what I am already doing on first one but it was failing.  I created a second one thinking maybe saving to file would work but it did not either.  It works on small data but when data is huge, it fails.

Comment: I skimmed over the first version and really only looked at the second one. It looks like the `plink` command is timing out on larger data. Does it complete successfully if you run it directly on the command line?

Comment: @Wyatt, You are right.  I ran the command on power shell and after couple seconds I got a Fatal error that server sent disconnect request.  Is it a plink limitation or server is setup that way?  If its plink, do you know any alternative to plink that work the same way?

Comment: I would guess that it's because of the way the server is configured. Do you have access to a Linux box where you can try it out with `ssh`? Or you might be able to run `ssh` using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) if you're running Windows 10. You could also try [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) and avoid the shell altogether.

Comment: When I use a ssh client (teraterm) and run the command, I get all results. I converted my code to use paramiko but still getting like 10% data and it cuts off.  I added my code in my main questions.  I runs and ends fine without any errors.

Comment: With Paramiko, I think you probably want to use [`exec_command`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.3/api/client.html?highlight=exec_command#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) instead of opening an interactive shell.

Comment: @Wyatt, I updated the code and followed your advice.  It is giving me error.

Comment: I ran into some issues with `exec_command` also. The solution for me was to pass in `get_pty=True`.

Comment: BTW, `subprocess.check_output(connectString, shell=True)` is outright dangerous from a security perspective. What if a user provides a password that contains `; rm -rf ~` or whatever the platform-local Windows equivalent is? Much safer to pass an explicit argument list rather than a string.

Answer (score 1):

According to [plink ssh not working with multiple commands passed in a file. - 65059 - The Cisco Learning Network](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/65059), this is a problem with Cisco routers and thus is not Python-related.

- [SSH using public key authentication to ... - Cisco Support Community](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/ssh-using-public-key-authentication-to-ios-and-big-outputs/ta-p/3122001) says that as soon as Cisco see EOF on input, it drops *both* sides of the connection even though according to TCP rules, it should only close the input socket. A workaround it suggests is to delay the EOF until all the output has been downloaded. It uses a quick & dirty `sleep` but that is unreliable for scripting.
- [Putty Dies with Large Output : networking - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/t01za/putty_dies_with_large_output/) says it's an MTU issue. The symptom is not being able to get more than about one screen of information:

  > I've come across a few MTU-related issues that manifested in terminal
  >   emulators in a similar manner. Usually it's some sort of
  >   point-to-point leased line that's carried in a VLAN where the added
  >   bytes for tagging mess things up and drop the frame in transit. When
  >   that happens, shorter output will go through fine, but longer output
  >   will just kill the session. Sometimes gracefully, other times not.

**In fact, the last one seems to be the correct explanation.** It's not the EOF that triggers the connection drop, it's the additional data after the command that just happens to contain it. Another workaround on the 1st link is to insert a couple of newlines between input commands -- looking at things this way, they serve as the padding in place of one that the broken transmission logic would otherwise insert itself and choke on it.